# Setting the max value of an input field to the value of a label

Tags: javascript, c#, html, input

I have an input field (type = number) and a label. I am trying to set the `max` attribute of the input field to the value of the label.

I have tried in different ways to no avail:

1)

```
<input id="Input1" type="number" step="any" min="1" max='<%#Convert.ToDecimal(Label1.InnerText) %>'>
```

2)

```
function setMaxTonnes() {
    var input = document.getElementById("<%= Input1.ClientID %>");
    var maxValue = document.getElementById("<%= Label1.ClientID %>").innerText;
    input.setAttribute("max", maxValue);
}

<input type="number" step="any" min="1" onfocus="setMaxTonnes()">
```

There are no errors which return with either of these efforts but it doesn't prevent me from entering a value greater than the value stored in Label1.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the asp variable is corrected output in the compiled markup? Try to inspect with DevTools if the input element actually gets your max value. 
Your example looks accurate, `<input type="number" step="any" min="1" max="12">` does work fine.

Comment: Yes putting a number in the max attribute works fine as you say. I just can't get it to work with another variable.

Comment: Did you verify that <%#Convert.ToDecimal(Label1.InnerText) %> actually output a number in the markup?

Comment: It doesn't produce an output when used as the max attribute. However, if I set a variable and set it to Convert.ToDecimal‌​(Label1.InnerText), it does.